# How can someone else read my Text Messages

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

someone I know reads my text messages by tapping our phones together as in the same style of sending pictures by bluetooth.  How is this possible and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably using NFC (Near Field Communication), or S Beam, both communication capabilities built into the Samsung Galaxies. They allow data transfer between devices in close proximity.

You can prevent this activity by electing to close the channels of communication.

Settings > Wireless & Networks > More Settings > File/Data transfer
Turn NFC OFF
Turn S Beam OFF

Comment: Just a note to others that may read this post with a similar question - devices with NFC and running Android 4.0 or higher also have this capability, regardless of manufacturer.  It's called Android Beam on non-Samsung devices.  Turning off NFC like wbogacz mentioned prevents communication.

Comment: Isn't it possible to disable the automatic sending of text messages without turning off S-Beam or NFC completely?

Comment: Android Beam doesn't send any data unless the user of the *sending* device taps the screen to send what's displayed.  You can't just suck messages out of someone's phone by putting your own phone near it.